# Elastic Bean Stalk CLI Windows - Failed to Create Process Error?

Tags: python, windows, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We have navigated to my development folder in command prompt.

`C:\Users\ABC\Code\Dev`

Now when I try to do a `eb` or `eb init`

I get the below error

[image: Elastic Bean Error]

Python 3.4 is installed. Can that be a problem?

There is no reference to this error in the Amazon Docs as well.

It's a standard Node.JS/ExpressJS Project.

Please guide.

Cheers and Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got help from AWS Forums.

Run `python eb-script.py` command in `Python34\Scripts` directory.

It should be the same as running `eb` command.

And `eb` is up and running.

Try hitting `eb --help`

Cheers! :)

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem on Windows 10.

I installed Python to `c:\Program Files\Python\Python35` and I believe the space in the path caused the problem.

In the `eb-script.py` file in the `c:\Program Files\Python\Python35\Scripts` folder edit the first line to be quoted, like this:

```
#!"c:\program files\python\python35\python.exe"
```

Obviously you need it to match your own installation path.

Answer (score 0):

It's because for Windows, newer Python by default installs in-

```
c:\users\<USER_NAME>\appdata\local\programs\python\python<VERSION>-<PLATFORM>
```

e.g.

```
c:\users\seriouscoder\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32
```

If you have chosen a different location during Python installation, you will see wrong path to "*python.exe*" in "***eb-script.py***" file.

Change it so that it points to "*python.exe*" found in your Python installation directory.

Lastly, there are a total of 3 paths that should be added to your Windows **Path** under **System variables**-

```
<PYTHON_INSTALLATION_DIRECTORY>;
<PYTHON_INSTALLATION_DIRECTORY>\Scripts;
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Python\Scripts;
```

e.g.

```
c:\users\seriouscoder\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32;
c:\users\seriouscoder\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Scripts;
c:\users\seriouscoder\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\Scripts;
```

Again, verify all paths by visiting them and apply accordingly following your installation paths.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this just now and fixed via:

```
pip uninstall awsebcli
pip install awsebcli
```